# New to mySQL Relationships

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mySQL relastionships and I'm wondering if you can help me out.

This is what I want to do:

***Users Table***

```
user_id
user_name
pass_word
permission_id
```

***Permissions Table***

```
p_id
permission_name
permission_type
```

I want to create a relationship between p_id (permissions table) & permission_id (user table) so when I query the user table it also brings through the corresponding permission name & type?

Is this possible or am I getting it all wrong?

Should I just use joins?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  u.user_id, 
        u.user_name, 
        u.pass_word,
        p.permission_name,
        p.permission_type
FROM Users u
  INNER JOIN Permissions p
ON u.permission_id  = p.p_id;
```

Max.